# A quiz question in number theory related to chinese remainder theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying quiz questions of previous year in number theory and I was unable to solve this particular problem.

[image]

> I tried by taking various integers ie fixing a and b and then trying to finding k and also letting that such a k exists and then equating both sides.( By this I got a-b = 11y -9x)But the problem is that I don't know of a method which is rigorous.

So, kindly tell how I can approach this question by rigorous method.

Comment: *Hint*: how many positive integers less than 100 are there?

Comment: Never post unsearchable images.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can solve this using CRT.  I like using Bezout coeffs.  So, since $-4\cdot11+5\cdot9=1$ we have an isomorphism between $\Bbb Z_{99}$ amd $\Bbb Z_{11}\times\Bbb Z_9$, given by $\varphi(x,y)=-44y+45x$.

So $\varphi(a,b)=-44b+45a\bmod{99}$ is our solution.  Thus there is only one solution between $0$ and $100$.

Comment: Taking $b-a=0$ for example, $\varphi(a,b)=a+44(a-b)$ can be arbitrary between $0$ and $100$ (not inclusive, both).